# ImportError: No module named None

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Test cases ***
TestDB
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params    None    database='TestDB', user='system', password='system', host='10.91.41.101', port=1521
```

Please help - the error is:

ImportError: No module named None

Comment: Could you work on formatting the source, adding the imports and the custom keywords you're using, and formulating a question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error most probably comes from the way you call `Connect To Database Using Custom Params` - the first argument you're passing, which should be the value for the `dbapiModuleName`, is passed as a string object, with the value "None".

If you wanted to call it with the value `None` object (as it's written in the library's help), that should have been `${None}` in robotframework format.
I doubt that's going to work though - the DatabaseLibrary probably needs some DB type identifier. So if you are using postgres for example, you'd call it with "psycopg2":

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    psycopg2    database='TestDB', user='username', password='mypass', host='10.1.1.2', port=1521
```

Have in mind you'd need the DB driver already installed through pip, `psycopg2` in the case of the example here.

*P.S. please don't paste actual credentials in SO.*

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question *should* have been posted something like this...

---

**Issue**

When attempting to execute the following test case in Robot Framework, I receive the following error: `ImportError: No module named None`

Here is the test case in question:

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestDB
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params None database='TestDB', user='system', password='system', host='10.91.41.101', port=1521
```

---

If so, *your issue may be as simple as **spacing***. Robot Framework can accept pipes as delimiters, but if you choose to use spaces, *you must use 2 or more*.

Based on your copy/paste, it looks like you have only one space between `Connect To Database Using Custom Params` and `None` (which, I'm assuming you're specifying as the DB API Python module the system default - not sure if that's recommended or supported). Make sure you have at least two spaces (I generally try for 4 unless I have a lot of parameters) between keywords and their parameters.

So:

- Make sure you have at least two spaces between the keyword and parameters. [Here is the keyword in question's reference](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params).
- Verify that you don't need to specify the Python database driver for the database you are using. Based on the port you've specified, I'm guessing it's an Oracle database. [Here's a list of Python Oracle drivers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle#DB_API_2.0_Drivers).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and read on it for hours not knowing I hadn't created a `.env` file yet. credit to a friend who brought me to this page. (which gave me the hint on what I was missing).
I created a `.env` file in my root folder where the manage.py file is and configured my database settings and voila. Thanks Suraj